# Why isn't pcre2grep found in the official Ubuntu repositories under the name pcre2grep?

Tags: apt, official-repositories

Why isn't `pcre2grep` found in the official Ubuntu repositories under the name `pcre2grep`, though `pcregrep` is found by [`pcregrep`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pcregrep)?

`pcre2grep` is currently a part of [`pcre2-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pcre2-utils)

Also it would be nice to have a `pcre` package, which would be a wrapper for `pcre2-utils`

Comment: Could you explain what kind of answer you are looking for? Are you hoping that someone from Canonical will explain why they chose to name the package one way and not the way you prefer?

Comment: Why? `apt search pcre2grep` will give you the correct package. What is the problem with this approach? In addition the package contains [two programs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/pcre2-utils/filelist) that is closely related.

Comment: It comes from Debian as a single package with that name. You can ask the Debian maintainer for their reasoning. If you are willing to contribute effort, you might be able to convince them to change.

Comment: @terdon yes, why one way, and not the logical one ??

Comment: @vidarlo `apt install pcre2grep` won't, it says only `Unable to locate package pcre2grep` and gives no suggestions for `pcre2-utils`

Comment: @vstepaniuk No, `apt install pcre2grep` will not work. But `apt search pcre2grep` will indicate the correct package. There's many packages where the name doesn't match one (or more) of the binaries.